# How to use Scapy library in Robot framework?

Tags: python, robotframework, scapy

I am using Robot framework (RFW) to test protocol testing stuff. I need to send Protocol (BGP, OSPF, DNS, DHCPv6, STP, SIP etc) traffic to my device under test.

I have analyzed "Rammbock Library", but I think it's not fulfilling my requirements. I am familiar with Scapy to send protocol traffic. So I am planning to use Scapy library in RFW.

I got following links:

- https://github.com/hanyong123/my-autotest/blob/master/switch_auto_test/scapyLibary.py
- https://github.com/nickrobinson/robotframework-dhcpv6library

But I am not getting idea on how to use this in RFW. I mean the keywords.

Anybody have idea on following questions.

1. How to build a packet in this library?
2. How to view the packet?
3. How to send that packet?

Answer (score 1):

RF has keyword in BuiltIn to call a method of a object.

for example - scapy object have show() or show2() method to display a frame.

```
""" contents of s.py (as a library) """
from scapy.all import *
def make_ether_icmp_pkt():
    return Ether()/ICMP()


#------------ test --------------------
*** Settings ***
Library  s.py  WITH NAME  S

*** Test Cases ***
simple
  ${P}=  S.make_ether_icmp_pkt
  call method  ${P}  show
  Log  ${P.type}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Could you please explain little more? I am unable to get this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1， 3: scapy itself can do it - for RF keyword you need to convert scapy module as a RF library, and loaded as a remote library if you use scapy in remote machine.

2. protocol decode you can use tshark - command-line tool of wireshark, to decode captured packets in .pcap file.